# Streaming data from Google Cloud Storage to an FTP Server

Tags: python, ftp, google-cloud-storage, ftplib

I'm trying to use [gcsfs](https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#module-ftplib) to transfer a CSV by lines/chunks from Cloud Storage to an FTP server. I have large files in GCS that I can't store in-memory so I am trying to test this way.

```
from ftplib import FTP
import gcsfs
from urllib import request
import io

ftp = FTP('my-ftp-server')

fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='my-project')

with fs.open('myFile.csv') as f:
    ftp.storlines("STOR myFile.csv", f)
```

but I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-d461792392dd> in <module>
      1 with fs.open('myfile') as f:
----> 2     ftp.storlines("STOR myFile.csv", f)

~\.conda\envs\py3.7\lib\ftplib.py in storlines(self, cmd, fp, callback)
    530         with self.transfercmd(cmd) as conn:
    531             while 1:
--> 532                 buf = fp.readline(self.maxline + 1)
    533                 if len(buf) > self.maxline:
    534                     raise Error("got more than %d bytes" % self.maxline)

TypeError: readline() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this or achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, [`fsspec.AbstractFileSystem`](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fsspec.spec.AbstractFileSystem) (on which `GCSFileSystem` is based), particularly its [`readline` method](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fsspec.spec.AbstractBufferedFile.readline), does not seem to be compatible with ftplib.

---

Do you need to use `FTP.storlines` (text mode)? Cannot you use [`FTP.storbinary`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.storbinary) (binary mode)?

```
with fs.open('myFile.csv') as f:
    ftp.storbinary("STOR myFile.csv", f)
```

`FTP.storbinary` transfers the file by chunks (defined by an optional parameter `blocksize` with the default value of 8192).

---

If not, you will have to implement a wrapper class with an API compatible with the `FTP.storlines`:

```
class GCSFileSystemCompat:

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def readline(self, size):
        return f.readline()

with fs.open('myFile.csv') as f,
    ftp.storlines("STOR myFile.csv", GCSFileSystemCompat(f))
```

*(untested, but it should give you the idea)*

Comment: This is great, thank you. [FTP.storbinary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.storbinary) uses the read() method and I'm trying to avoid reading the whole file at once. But please correct me if my understanding is wrong? I'm setting this up as a cloud function so need to be mindful of memory.

Comment: You have very low expectantions if you believe that such a mainstream FTP library as ftplib would be implemented that badly. – `FTP.storbinary` calls `fp.read(blocksize)`, with `blocksize` being an optional parameter of the method with the default value as low as 8192.